# DialogFlow -Web Client - using Sign-in Helper?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using the Actions on Google Signin helper to leverage Account Linking for Google Sign-in. The setup is using JSON and invoking it within the Actions on Google simulator or Google Assistant invokes the required helper. Is there a way to use the signin helper for the web client or is there a preferred way to do Account Linking for Google Sign-in for web client?

The JSON for siginin I am using is

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
    "fulfillmentText": "Hello There!",
    "items": [
      {
        "simpleResponse": {
          "textToSpeech": "Please sign in to access!"
        }
      }
    ],
    "source": "askaibot.com"
      },
      "systemIntent": {
    "data": {
      "@@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValueSpec"
    },
    "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is any means to use Google Signin for the web client when using webhook and JSON setup. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Thanks Prisoner, for responding! Yes, I was referring to the webdemo available as a part of integrations or the assistant that runs on the web page noted for e.g. https://bot.dialogflow.com/60710e58-7590-423d-a533-79efcec0f2aa.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify what you mean by "the web client" exactly? An Assistant that runs in a web page? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Web Demo" integration for Dialogflow isn't the Assistant. Although it lets you communicate with an agent built with Dialogflow, it doesn't have all the features that the Assistant does, and does not use the Actions on Google platform and features.

In particular, this means that it does not allow for Google Sign-In.

However...

You *can* use [Google Sign-In for websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to have users log into a web page of yours. You can then use the Dialogflow [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis) to build a chat client on your web page that will send user messages to a server that will send them to Dialogflow and include the user authentication with those messages. Your webhook will need to make sure it distinguishes between a message from the Assistant vs a message from your web page, get the auth info differently, and respond accordingly. All of this, however, is not as simple as what is offered through Actions on Google.